# Fixing LWJGLException "Pixel format not accelerated" error when running exported game in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I'm currently developing a game using Eclipse and encountered an issue when exporting and testing it on another computer. The game runs smoothly on my own computer, but on the other computer, I encountered the `Pixel format not accelerated` error within the `createDisplay()` function (specifically, in the line `Display.create(...)`). I launched the JAR file from the command line to identify the error and confirm the issue.

```
public static void createDisplay() {
    System.out.println("test1");
    ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3, 2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);
    
    try {
        System.out.println("test2");
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        Display.create(new PixelFormat().withDepthBits(24), attribs);
        Display.setTitle("Our First Display!");
        
        System.out.println("test3");
        
        GL11.glEnable(GL13.GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GL11.glViewport(0,0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    lastFrameTime = getCurrentTime();
}
```

Comment: Its possible the other computer doesn't have drivers that supports OpenGL 3.2 or higher. Try creating the display without the pixel format and context attributes. Then put "System.out.println("OpenGL version: " + GL11.glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION));" after the display is created to see what version of OpenGL the other computer supports. If it is lower than 3.2, check for new graphics card drivers.